# Text file probability calculation (Markov Chain) - Python

Tags: python, string, count, probability, markov-chains

I'm in a bad situation. I need to program something, that's a level over my capacity.

I have been given a text with 10k words, the file is called (test_file.txt).
My question to u guys are:
How do I get my program to count every single words, and every single letter, so I can calculate a probability over the words, to see which word and letters are represented most.

I know it's something with strings, all I done at this moment is:

```
import codecs
import sys
import random

fh = codecs.open("test_file.txt", encoding="utf-8")

fh.close()

omega = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'}

def Markov(text_file):
    with open("test_file.txt") as t:
        text = t.read()

    text = [' '.join(data.split(' ')) if i !=''] 
    text = [i.lower() for i in data if i.isalpha()]

    chains = {i:[] for i in data}
```

Is this Correct?

I need your help guys.

Comment: When you test it with a small file of 20 words, does it do what you want?

Comment: I dont even know, how to test it with small files, thats the problem.
Hope u can help me.

Comment: You call doing something that's over your head a "bad situation". I'd call it "learning".

Comment: The reason I call it "bad situation" is that I can't get further already. I know what to do, I understand the task and the meaning, but I just can't code it.

Comment: If you can't code it, it means that you don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. This isn't related to Markov Chains. At All.
2. Python actually has some really nice builtins that will make this more or less trivial.

I won't spoon-feed an answer, but I don't want to leave you high and dry on this one. The gist is that depending on your specifics, this can be done in a couple lines using the `Counter` object in `python`.

```
from collections import Counter

text = open("test_file.txt").read().lower()
letter_freqs = Counter(text)

word_freqs = Counter(text.split())
```

Depending on what end result you're looking for this may or may not be sufficient, but this should get you far enough that the rest should be pretty trivial.

Comment: Right now theres not so much Markov Chains over it, but further my project will include Markov Chains, this is just the beginning.
Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you're interested in moving onto Markov Chains I have a gist up here: https://gist.github.com/Slater-Victoroff/6227656.

Also, if you found an answer helpful, don't forget to accept it (check mark under the vote count.)

Comment: Dude it works perfectly. Now I need to convert these numbers to a percentage number.
It would probably be something like:
(Letters_representation/text)*100
When I got the letter_representation, I need to know the exact representation of all letters in the text.

So i need to define a function, that can solve this for every single letter, and every single word. Right?